# Translate data from API in in template with an an other API

Tags: twig

im doing a package tracker with PHP / TWIG , and would like to translate results in an other language, so i have a google translate APi

in my twig file i  have this :

```html
{% for item in item.origin_info.trackinfo %}
    <div class="status-{{item.checkpoint_status}}">
        <p> {{item.StatusDescription}}. </p>
        <hr/>
{% endfor  %}
```

And i would like to translate each `{{ item.StatusDescription }}`. Could you tell me how to do ?
my function to translate is :

```php
function translation($str){
    $url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=fr&dt=t&q=" . $str;

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($result);
    $traduction = $data[0][0][0];
    $lang = $data[2];
    
    return $traduction;
}
```

Comment: Please may you format your question so others can read it?

Comment: Add an extra [filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters) to twig which call your (global) function `translate`

Comment: do you have an exemple please? i dont get it

Comment: Do you use any framework like symfony?

Comment: im using twig with like : 

  $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(__DIR__ . '/templates');
  $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register a custom filter into `twig` which allows you to call global functions.

```php
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('translate', 'translation'));
```

First parameter `translate` is what the filter will be called in `twig`, the second is your global function `translation`. You now can use this filter in any template, e.g.

```html
{% for item in item.origin_info.trackinfo %}
    <div class="status-{{item.checkpoint_status}}">
        <p> {{ item.StatusDescription | translate }}. </p>
        <hr/>
    </div>
{% endfor  %}
```

---

If you need more than one extra function, filter, test, ... you are better off with creating an extension. See [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension) for more information on this.

Comment: thank you very much it works.
however i to make the translatation possible i need to replace the space between word by a "-", and then when it will be translate, re change . Do you know if i can put a function replace here ?

Comment: I suggest you just do that in your php function then, e.g. `"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=fr&dt=t&q=" . str_replace(' ', '-', $str);`